# Unable to find id's for react native apps only for splash screen visibility/text boxes using appium inspector/UI automator

Tags: react-native, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator, appium-desktop

react-native currently supports contentDescription via accessibilityLabel. This is great for clickable elements, but not so great for testing other things like splash screen visibility/text boxes using appium inspector/UI automator even developers after adding the unique id's.

can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **cont-Desc** in the your splash screen, you can check if the screen is displayed using **isDisplayed()** method.

```
public boolean isSplashScreenVisible(){
    try{
        MobileElement element = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("automation id here");
        return element.isDisplayed();
     }catch(Expection e){
        return false;
     }
}
```

Alternately you can check if splash screen is displayed like;

```
List<MobileElement> element = driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId("automation id here");
if(element.size()>0){
   //screen is displayed
}else{
  //screen is not displayed
}
```

Comment: Hi suban thanks for your reply but my question is currently my dev team added accessibility Id's for all elements but only for clickable elements while inspecting in appium inspector/uiautomator content-desc is showing for remaining elements like text boxes content-desc is not showing.

Comment: you can ask them to add cont-desc for each screen.